# What does this LogCat error mean?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, logcat

Im trying to run an example off E3roid examples. Except when i do, i get a force close on the page. Here is the logcat error. By looking at it, can you tell me what it means and what is the problem?

```
02-28 20:31:51.429: D/AndroidRuntime(1779): Shutting down VM
02-28 20:31:51.429: W/dalvikvm(1779): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
02-28 20:31:51.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1779): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 20:31:51.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1779): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{and.roid/and.roid.AndroidActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: and.roid.AndroidActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/and.roid-1.apk]
02-28 20:31:51.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
02-28 20:31:51.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
02-28 20:31:51.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-28 20:31:51.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
02-28 20:31:51.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 20:31:51.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-28 20:31:51.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
02-28 20:31:51.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 20:31:51.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-28 20:31:51.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
02-28 20:31:51.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
02-28 20:31:51.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 20:31:51.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1779): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: and.roid.AndroidActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/and.roid-1.apk]
02-28 20:31:51.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
02-28 20:31:51.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
02-28 20:31:51.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
02-28 20:31:51.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
02-28 20:31:51.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
02-28 20:31:51.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     ... 11 more
02-28 20:31:57.820: I/Process(1779): Sending signal. PID: 1779 SIG: 9
02-28 20:34:48.691: D/AndroidRuntime(2072): Shutting down VM
02-28 20:34:48.691: W/dalvikvm(2072): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
02-28 20:34:48.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2072): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 20:34:48.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2072): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{and.roid/and.roid.AndroidActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: and.roid.AndroidActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/and.roid-1.apk]
02-28 20:34:48.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
02-28 20:34:48.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
02-28 20:34:48.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-28 20:34:48.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2072):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
02-28 20:34:48.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2072):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 20:34:48.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2072):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-28 20:34:48.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
02-28 20:34:48.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2072):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 20:34:48.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2072):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-28 20:34:48.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2072):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
02-28 20:34:48.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2072):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
02-28 20:34:48.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2072):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 20:34:48.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2072): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: and.roid.AndroidActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/and.roid-1.apk]
02-28 20:34:48.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2072):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
02-28 20:34:48.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2072):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
02-28 20:34:48.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2072):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
02-28 20:34:48.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2072):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
02-28 20:34:48.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
02-28 20:34:48.691: E/AndroidRuntime(2072):     ... 11 more
02-28 20:34:56.511: I/Process(2072): Sending signal. PID: 2072 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added AndroidActivity to your AndroidManifest?

Comment: Cool but how do i declare it?

Comment: `<activity android:name=".ActivityNameGoesHere"/>` 

Don't forget the dot, put this inside your activity element

Comment: Thanks! smartlemon aka winner

Answer (score 0):

It probably means that you did not properly declare your activity in your manifest file.  Typically what happens is that you'll make an activity, but forget to include it in your manifest, which is when these slightly strange messages appear.

Comment: How can i declare it in this android manifest, if the file is called "robot"?    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <application
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
           android:name=".AndroidActivity" 
     android:label="@string/app_name" >
       <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <activity android:name="robot"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

Comment: Why do you have `<activity android:name="robot"/>` _inside_ the `intent-filter`?